# If I login to a PS4 from a different region to my PSN account can I use a payment method from the the PS4s region to make purchases on my account?

Tags: ps4, region-lock, playstation-plus

I have a PSN account set to a different region than I am currently in, so I am unable to buy PS Plus.

Can I log in with my account on my friend's device that is set to my current region, subscribe to PS Plus, and then login with this account on my own device so PS Plus will be active?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do this.

Your account is associated with the region not the PS4 so even if you login to your friend's PS4 it will still ask for a payment method from the region of your account.

I'm assuming the problem is that you no longer have a valid payment method from your original region.

If you no longer have a way to pay from the same region as your PSN account there are a couple of things you can do.

1. Set up a new account on your PS4 for the new region and buy PS
   Plus on this account. This is easy to do and you can still access PS
   Plus features on your old account but you will loose access to any
   free PS Plus games that are associated with your old account.
2. Buy PSN Gift cards from your original region online and use the
   credit to buy the PS Plus subscription on you original account.